# I am NOt able to run Android emulator? does not have any error?

Tags: android, emulation

[i am a beginner in android and trying to run my first android project. 
my haxm is working properly, i have set ram size 512mb as it is according to haxm size.
it does not give any error msg. and shows only blank screen on emulator.

can any one help me plz?][1]

```
 Messages of AVD:Nexus_5_API_23
C:\Users\Chinky\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23
Warning: No DNS servers found
emulator: device fd:732
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 0 0 240 320
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 6 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'
```

Messages of APP window

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is ready: Nexus_5_API_23 [emulator-5554]
Target device: Nexus_5_API_23 [emulator-5554]
Installing APK: C:\Users\Chinky\Desktop\android\HappyBirthday\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday
Installing com.example.android.happybirthday
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday"


Messages of Event Log
12:17:37 PM Gradle sync started
12:19:23 PM Gradle sync completed
12:19:27 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
12:19:38 PM Gradle build finished in 13s 932ms
12:20:38 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
12:20:46 PM Gradle build finished in 8s 624ms
```

Blank screen on emulator.

Comment: i guess you just need to update your haxm driver. It says "it fails to get latest version".

Comment: Sometimes the emulator can take time to load and can be kind of slow and buggy, I think for haxm you should set ram to 1024mb but if you have an android device I would recommend you connect it in debug mode and run your app testing directly on the device it will save you a lot of time.